# “And those who were seen dancing, were thought to be crazy, by those who could not hear the music.” Are these commas required?

Tags: punctuation, commas

Just spotted this as an answer in Quora:

> And those who were seen dancing, were thought to be crazy, by those who could not hear the music.

At first look, I thought the comma between *dancing* and *crazy* was wrong. Will this be grammatically wrong? What about the comma between *crazy* and *by*? Is that wrong too?

Comment: It needs no commas anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

The commas are unnecessary, but they're not grammatically incorrect. The meaning of the sentence is clear.

In days of olde, when English was just a lass, excessive commafication was commonplace. They told the reader where to pause when reading and speaking the written word, as these do.

Sometimes even today writers will use a comma to separate the subject from the predicate: it's rare, but not unheard of, but, like the elusive Sasquatch, even more rarely seen. These two commas turn the sentence into a "found poem" of sorts:

> And those who were seen dancing   [grammatical subject]
>   Were thought to be crazy   [main passive voice verb phrase]
>   By those who could not hear the music   [passive voice agent]

Commas cause contention. Some like 'em and some don't. The rules about their use are like overcooked spaghetti: even a tasty sauce can't make them palatable.

Comment: Bill, +1 for the last sentence!